# Parse error in a `do` block on input `<-`

Tags: haskell, monads, parse-error

In my textbook, there is an example of how to take out the first and third character from a string using parsers. I have tried to write it down as it stands in the book.

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]

item = \inp -> case inp of
    []-> []
    (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]

p = do 
    x <- item
    item 
    y <- item
    return (x,y)
```

However I get the message:

```
dataTest.hs:47:11:
parse error on input ‘<-’
Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?
```

As I was not able to figure out what went wrong, I wrote down this for a less abstract version of the code:

```
q = item >>= \x1 -> 
    item >>= \x2 ->
    item >>= \x3 -> 
    return (x1, x3)
```

But as shown below:

```
*Main> q "abc"
([('a',"bc")],[('a',"bc")],[('a',"bc")])
```

I get the wrong output.

So I have two questions:

1. How should I write p?
2. How should I write q?

Comment: I have a hunch that the definition of `item` is wrong (it shouldn't be just a function, that makes it be in the entirely wrong monad for a parser), and that if it compiles like this, then the definition of `Parser` is wrong too (perhaps it's defined with `type`? You cannot define own monads for things defined with `type`.)

Comment: I'll post how I wrote the parser.

Comment: Right, that's about what I figured. You won't be able to get do notation to work correctly for the parser with that type definition.

Comment: In that case, my book has the wrong definition. Can you post the real definition?

Comment: @mcNogard It's the instance that's the problem. Make it a Monad.

Comment: @mcNogard You can do `import Control.Monad.State; type Parser a = StateT String [] a` and then you will have an instance that works. But you may need to do other adjustments, like adding `StateT $` after `item =`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a formatting thing. Start a newline:

```
p = do
    x <- item
    item
    y <- item
    return (x,y)
```

As for `q`, remember that `do {x <- item; f x}` is equivalent to `item >>= \x -> f x`, and the second one is redundant, so:

```
q = do
    x1 <- item 
    item
    x3 <- item
    return (x1, x3)
```

...which is equivalent to `p`.

Comment: The p is compiling now, but it still gives me the wrong result. p "abcd" gives the result ([('a',"bcd")],[('a',"bcd")],[('a',"bcd")]). I want to get the result [('a', 'c'), "d"], which is the result in my book.

Comment: @mcNogard You may have written the in-line `item` accidentally. Ie, it should just be `do {x <- item; y <- item; return (x,y)}` or just `(,) <$> item <*> item` in Applicative style. That's probably what you're looking for. But that's another question.

Comment: Ah, but wait: You're working in the function monad, not the Parser monad! You need to define `Parser` as another type and make a monad instance. Of course it won't work if you're not using the right monad!